# jUnit Testing of Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am doing unit testing of a controller:

```
    @Test
    public void testStudentInSectionForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/organizationnamanement"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("organizationnamanement"));
    }
```

Here I am getting an error:

```
Url expected <organizationnamanement> but was null;
```

Can anybody tell me how I can resolve this?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error in the test case? Are you getting error with only    mockMvc.perform(get("/organizationnamanement"))           .andExpect(status().isOk()) ?

Comment: .andExpect(redirectedUrl("organizationnamanement"));

here is my error

IF i do  .andExpect(redirectedUrl(null));

it works

Comment: so is your get method redirecting it. Both of them are the same Url, right ? That could be the problem

Comment: redirectedUrl method asserts that the request was redirected to the given URL. This error means your response.getRedirectedUrl() is null.